# What is the best way to manage number with currency?

Tags: iphone, core-data, numbers, currency

In my application it's possible to store a price for every object and the user can also choose its preferred currency.
**What is the best way to store and manage number with currency in iPhone SDK?**

More infos about my app:
It uses Core Data.
Number that can be stored must be of type xxx.xx (e.g. 100.00).
How can I sort these numbers ascending or descending?
What kind of attribute I must set in my entity to store a number like this?

Have you got links, docs, source or guides to show me examples? I never user number with currency, then I've got some problems with them :)

Thanks a lot,
Matthew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in GP (gold pieces) with a conversion factor ;)

It doesn't look like there's a datatype for currency, so storing the number and decimal part, and a setting for the current currency, is probably as good as you're going to get. See this: [HowTo for newbie: Managing currency in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426779/howto-for-newbie-managing-currency-in-iphone-app)

Comment: Just to be clear, I was joking about the gold pieces thing... as far as just storing it as a number with a bit of data somewhere that says whether you're currently using dollars, euro, yen, etc should work. But it doesn't seem like Apple has created a datatype for this.

Comment: In my entity, what kind of attribute must I use? Float, double... Thanks!

Comment: Decimal because float and double can remove precision. The only annoying thing with NSDecimalNumber is the operators are messages instead of +-/*

Comment: For now, I believe I will not use operations with these number but if I'll use them, what do you mean with the phrase "the operators are messages instead of +-/*"? Is there some info about this on the Apple Developer Site? Thanks :)