# How can I prevent iPhone NSNumberFormatter from rounding?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to format large currency numbers like this:

```
NSNumber *testVal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: @"999999999999999993.00"];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setMaximumIntegerDigits:19];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [Formatters numberFormatterForField:f];
NSLog([formatter stringFromNumber:testVal]);
```

Ignoring the effect of Locale for a moment, I find that I consistently get the following output regardless of the rounding:

```
1,000,000,000,000,000,000
```

I expect:

```
999,999,999,999,999,993
```

I've tried changing the rounding with no effect.  Why does `NSNumberFormatter` insist on rounding up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSNumberFormatter` converts the number to a double before displaying, so that's not what you want. `NSDecimalNumber` has a `descriptionWithLocale:` method that should suit your needs.

See this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421463/should-i-use-nsdecimalnumber-to-deal-with-money/422442)

Comment: Actually, in my original code I'm given a double and need to format that. I had just switched to trying NSDecimalNumber to see if it made any difference (and it doesn't).  
I guess there's no way to avoid this loss of precision when NSNumberFormatter converts from a double to a string?

Comment: Doubles only have roughly 17-18 decimal digits of precision to begin with: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/93742-extended-vs-double-precision.html NSNumberFormatter cannot recover information that has already been lost