# Disable rounding up in NSNumberFormatter (working with locale)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I am working with several locale numbers. Example:

1. 1.234.567,89 - German
2. 1'234'567.89 - Switzerland
3. 1,234,567.89 - US

My code rounds UP the last digit after decimal separator:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

double myValue = [[formatter numberFromString:@"123.458"] doubleValue];
double myValue2 = [[formatter numberFromString:@"123.444"] doubleValue];

NSString *rezult = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myValue]];
NSString *rezult2 = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myValue2]];

NSLog(@"rezult = %@", rezult);  //gives 123.46 - incorrect
NSLog(@"rezult2 = %@", rezult2);//gives 123.44 - correct
```

Please suggest how to prevent rounding up.

Keep in mind that I cannot do it like this:

```
double aDouble = 1234.56789;
NSString *stri = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", aDouble];
NSLog(@"%@", stri); //result is 1234.56 - correct (not rounded up to 1234.57)
```

...because I have to set that *stri using *formatter (see above).

I guess there must be some additional settings to `NSNumberFormatter`, isn't it?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

Solution: after declaring NSNumberFormatter, say also:

```
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
```

Thanks to @Price for the fast solution. Subject closed.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703428/how-can-i-prevent-iphone-nsnumberformatter-from-rounding

Comment: Not duplicate, that guy do not use locale numbers.

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you use local numbers either. It is rounded when you print it not internally. Use NSDecimalNumber like they say.

Comment: I use locale: [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]; and that "duplicate" didn't help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add this:

```
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
```