# Core Data - Decimal Type for Currency

Tags: iphone, core-data

I read in a recent post that the Decimal data type is the best to use in Core Data to model currency since it doesn't have floating point issues.

I've searched the apple docs and google and can't seem to find any documentation on using the Decimal type.

Does anyone have a link to documentation on it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Use "Decimal" as the attribute type in your data model and NSDecimalNumber as the object type in your code.

Comment: This question might also be helpful to him: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421463/should-i-use-nsdecimalnumber-to-deal-with-money

Answer (score 7):

The 'decimal' type in Core Data relates to the Cocoa type `NSDecimalNumber`, and lo, here is its documentation: [NSDecimalNumber documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :-)

Answer (score 4):

Its because we don't want to get things like **$9.9999999998** instead of **$10**.

More Details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17107017/1239426