# How can I sum coreData attributes filtered by NSPredicate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hi I want to be able to sum an attribute (rowTotal) in my CoreData database after it has been filtered by a predicate which I have in place in the fetched results controller. The result would then be a subtotal for the order.

Initially I thought I could somehow just sum the values which are displayed in the tableCells but I have read that this doesn't work well as there may only be 10 tableCells for 100 items.

I have read a similar question (link below) which relates to putting the sum in a section header. I want a variation whereby i want the sum to be displayed and updated to a UILabel after any changes occur to the managedObjectContext.

[Sum a CoreData attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774589/sum-a-coredata-attribute)

I have tried the following code:

```
float subtotal = 0;
for (NSManagedObject *object in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
NSNumber *objectRowTotalNumber = [object valueForKey:@"rowTotal"];
float objectRowTotal = [objectRowTotalNumber floatValue];
subtotal = subtotal + objectRowTotal;
}
NSLog(@"Subtotal: %f", subtotal);
```

I have tried it in multiple locations in my code to see if I can get it to work. I have had no success and data doesn't show in the tableView with this code. I think its the following line that's giving me grief.

```
for (NSManagedObject *object in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects])
```

I get the sense that its actually creating a new managed object and interfering with the one that I have in place.

Here is the code for my fetched result controller

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
NSLog(@"I'm inside the method fetchedResultsController");


/*
 Set up the fetched results controller.
 */
// Create the fetch request for the entity.
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
OrderAppDelegate *appDelegate = 
(OrderAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Order" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the Predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"orderNumber == %@", orderNumberLabel.text];
NSLog(@"predicate is: %@",predicate);
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;


[aFetchedResultsController release];
[fetchRequest release];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Am I using the right code for this application? can you see anything that I am doing wrong?
Where should I be implementing the code?

Any guidance would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

As an aside, you can change this:

```
float subtotal = 0;
for (NSManagedObject *object in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
    NSNumber *objectRowTotalNumber = [object valueForKey:@"rowTotal"];
    float objectRowTotal = [objectRowTotalNumber floatValue];
    subtotal = subtotal + objectRowTotal;
}
NSLog(@"Subtotal: %f", subtotal);
```

To this:

```
CGFloat subtotal = [[[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.rowTotal"] floatValue]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried it in multiple locations in my code to see if I can get it to work. I have had no success

That code looks good to me, assuming the fetch request is OK and returns results. How many results do you get? Do they all have a nonzero "rowTotal" property? Is there an error thrown by this code or does `subtotal` just remain 0?

> and data doesn't show in the tableView with this code.

Assuming the code works and `subtotal` is > 0, you will then have to provide the result to the table view via its data source methods.

> Where should I be implementing the code?

It would be typical, but not required, to put your `- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController` method in your view controller subclass. Also, the summation chunk could go in, perhaps, `- (float)subtotal`.

Comment: Subtotal just remains at 0, but the reason for this is that it doesn't run the code in the loop for some reason. So subtotal just stays at the value it was set at. The fetch request does return results and I can add&delete etc, they all have a "rowTotal" property >0 and there are no errors thrown

Comment: Ahhhh :D resolved the problem. I removed `self.` from `for (NSManagedObject *object in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects])` and it now works as intended. Would you be able to tell me why the `self.` was having this effect just for my own understanding?

Comment: Calling `self.fetchedResultsController` means you are accessing your FRC via an accessor method, which you may have written yourself, or more likely, created via @property/@synthesize. Calling just `fetchedResultsController` means you are accessing your FRC instance variable ("ivar") directly, not through an accessor. In your case, I don't know why one works and the other doesn't - something is probably messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. To me it has worked. The calculation is based on integers..

```
int sum=0;
    for(NSManagedObject *object in self.runArray) {
        int value = [[object valueForKey:@"distance"] intValue];
        sum += value;

    }
```

If you want to make a sum with decimals, you can do the same but changing integers by double value

```
double sum=0;
    for(NSManagedObject *object in self.runArray) {
        double value = [[object valueForKey:@"distance"] doubleValue];
        sum += value;

    }
```