# Does XCode Floor "Min Value" and "Max Value" for Core Data Decimal Attributes?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, core-data

## Background

I, like scores of programmers before me, am working on an application that deals with money. I'm relatively new to Cocoa programming, but after reading through the manuals I decided that I would try to use Core Data because it provides a number of features that I want and *should* save me from re-inventing the wheel. Anyway, my question doesn't have anything to do with whether or not I should use Core Data: it has to do with the behavior of Core Data and XCode themselves.

**UPDATE:** I filed a bug report with Apple and was informed that it is a duplicate of problem ID 9405079. They are aware of the issue, but I have no idea when or if they are going to fix it.

## The Problem

For some reason that I cannot understand, *XCode floors the **Min Value** and **Max Value** constraints when I edit a Decimal property in my managed object model.* (I'm using Decimal properties for [the reasons described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421463/should-i-use-nsdecimalnumber-to-deal-with-money/422513#422513).)

Assume that I have a Core Data entity with a Decimal attribute named `value` (this is merely for illustration; I've used other attribute names, as well). I want it to have a value greater than 0, but because XCode will only allow me to specify a minimum value (inclusive), I set **Min Value** equal to `0.01`. Much to my surprise, this results in a validation predicate of `SELF >= 0`! I get the same result when I change the minimum value: all fractional values are truncated (the minimum value is floored). The maximum value has the same behavior.

By way of illustration, the `value` property in the following screenshot will result in validation predicates of `SELF >= 0` and `SELF <= 1`.

[image: value configured in XCode]

Strangely enough, though, *if I change the type of this property to either **Double** or **Float***, the validation predicates will change to `SELF >= 0.5` and `SELF <= 1.2`, as expected. Stranger still, if I create my own data model following the [*Core Data Utility Tutorial*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataUtilityTutorial/Articles/00_introduction.html), the validation predicates are set correctly *even for decimal properties*.

## Original Workaround

Since I can't find any way to fix this problem in XCode's managed object model editor, I have added the following code—indicated by the `begin workaround` and `end workaround` comments—to my application delegate's `managedObjectModel` method (this is the same application delegate that XCode provides by default when you create a new project that uses Core Data). Note that I am adding a constraint to keep the `Transaction` entity's `amount` property greater than 0.

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel) return managedObjectModel;

    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];

    // begin workaround
    NSEntityDescription *transactionEntity = [[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Transaction"];
    NSAttributeDescription *amountAttribute = [[transactionEntity attributesByName] objectForKey:@"amount"];
    [amountAttribute setValidationPredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF > 0"]]
                      withValidationWarnings:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"amount is not greater than 0"]];
    // end workaround

    return managedObjectModel;
}
```

## Questions

1. Is this really a bug in how XCode generates validation predicates for decimal properties in managed object models for Core Data?
2. If so, is there a better way to work around it than the ones I have described here?

## Repro Code

You should be able to reproduce this issue with the following sample code for a `DebugController` class, which prints out the constraints on every property in a managed object model to a label. This code makes the following assumptions.

- You have an application delegate named `DecimalTest_AppDelegate`
- Your application delegate has a `managedObjectContext` method
- Your managed object model is named "Wallet"

Take the following steps to use this code.

1. Instantiate the `DebugController` in Interface Builder.
2. Connect the controller's `appDelegate` outlet to your application delegate.
3. Add a wrapping label (`NSTextField`) to your user interface and connect the controller's `debugLabel` outlet to it.
4. Add a button to your user interface and connect its selector to the controller's `updateLabel` action.
5. Launch your application and press the button connected to the `updateLabel` action. This prints your managed object model's constraints to `debugLabel` and should illustrate the behavior that I've described here.

**DebugController.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
// TODO: Replace 'DecimalTest_AppDelegate' with the name of your application delegate
#import "DecimalTest_AppDelegate.h"


@interface DebugController : NSObject {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context;

    // TODO: Replace 'DecimalTest_AppDelegate' with the name of your application delegate
    IBOutlet DecimalTest_AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *debugLabel;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

- (IBAction)updateLabel:sender;

@end
```

**DebugController.m**

```
#import "DebugController.h"

@implementation DebugController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (context == nil)
    {
        context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[appDelegate managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    }
    return context;     
}

- (IBAction)updateLabel:sender
{
    NSString *debugString = @"";

    // TODO: Replace 'Wallet' with the name of your managed object model
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Wallet" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    NSArray *properties = [entity properties];

    for (NSAttributeDescription *attribute in properties)
    {
        debugString = [debugString stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n%@: \n", [attribute name]];
        NSArray *validationPredicates = [attribute validationPredicates];
        for (NSPredicate *predicate in validationPredicates)
        {
            debugString = [debugString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n", [predicate predicateFormat]];
        }
    }
    //  NSPredicate *validationPredicate = [validationPredicates objectAtIndex:1];
    [debugLabel setStringValue:debugString];
}

@end
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Yeah I verified the behavior, and I couldn't find anything that would indicate that it is being saved in the .xcdatamodeld/entities file incorrectly, so I would suspect that it isn't really xcode that is doing it. probably the runtime environment, perhaps you should file a bug report. Is there a special reason why you would need to use Decimal type?

Comment: @Grady Thanks, I'm glad that I'm not the only one running into this. To answer your question, I'm using Decimal numbers for the accuracy that they provide (base-10 math instead of floating-point precision), as discussed earlier [on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421463/should-i-use-nsdecimalnumber-to-deal-with-money) [and elsewhere](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/23/cocoa-tutorial-dont-be-lazy-with-nsdecimalnumber-like-me/).

Comment: I guess you will just have to implement your own -(BOOL)validate<key>:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError, would be closest to default behavior.

Comment: @Grady Thanks for your advice! I just updated my question to include your workaround. I had actually considered filing a bug report, but I wasn't sure precisely where and/or how to do so. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Comment: @Grady Okay, I filed a bug report with Apple. I would link to it here, but it doesn't look like Apple provides public URLs for their bugs? For what it's worth, the problem ID is 9585842.

Comment: @Chris, cool let me know what you find out.

Comment: **UPDATE:** My problem appears to be a duplicate of problem ID 9405079 (not that I can view it...).

Comment: This seems to still be an issue. I set a minimum value on a `Decimal` to `0.01`, and validation succeeds when testing against a `Decimal` of `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did another test, and I suspect that it has to do with the `compare:` method of `NSNumber` and `NSDecimalNumber`.

```
NSDecimalNumber * dn = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.2"];

if ([dn compare:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.2]]==NSOrderedSame) {
        NSLog(@"1.2==1.2");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"1.2!=1.2");
    }

    if ([[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.2] compare:dn]==NSOrderedSame) {
        NSLog(@"1.2==1.2");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"1.2!=1.2");
    }
```

Output is:

```
2011-06-08 14:39:27.835 decimalTest[3335:903] 1.2==1.2
2011-06-08 14:39:27.836 decimalTest[3335:903] 1.2!=1.2
```

**Edit:** The following workaround was originally a comment that I added to the question and was eventually adapted into the question body.

Using `-(BOOL)validate<key>:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError` you can implement behavior that is close to the default behavior (as [described here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/Articles/moValidation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002185)).

For example (taken from the question body, written by OP Chris):

```
-(BOOL)validateAmount:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {

    // Assuming that this is a required property...
    if (*ioValue == nil)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    if ([*ioValue floatValue] <= 0.0)
    {
        if (outError != NULL)
        {
            NSString *errorString = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(
                @"Amount must greater than zero", @"Transaction",
                @"validation: zero amount error");

            NSDictionary *userInfoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:errorString
                forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];

            // Assume that we've already defined TRANSACTION_ERROR_DOMAIN and TRANSACTION_INVALID_AMOUNT_CODE
            NSError *error = [[[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:TRANSACTION_ERROR_DOMAIN
                code:TRANSACTION_INVALID_AMOUNT_CODE
                userInfo:userInfoDict] autorelease];
            *outError = error;
        }

        return NO;
    }



  return YES;
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, I get the same behavior. You would think that `compare` would be commutative, but that doesn't appear to be the case. I wonder if in the first conditional statement the `NSNumber` is being converted into an `NSDecimalNumber`, and in the second conditional statement the `NSDecimalNumber` is being converted into an `NSNumber`—which is more prone to floating-point errors than `NSDecimalNumber` and thus fails the equality test...

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. Seems like the root of the problem, maybe if we file a bug report we will get a better answer

Comment: There shouldn't be a float problem with 1.2, I don't think anyway

Comment: Could you update your answer to include your suggestion to use `-(BOOL)validate<key>:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError`? That's the workaround that I chose to use and I want to credit you for it. If/when I get an update from Apple about this bug, I'll edit my question to include that information, as well.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update my question later to remove the redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very long shot but have you tried 1,2 instead of 1.2?

Comment: Oh, wouldn't that have been embarrassing... I just gave it a shot and the text field for **Max Value** automatically corrected my input to 1

Answer (score 0):

This is inportant: http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=86013D0FEFFA6CD1A626176C5D4EF9E2?doi=10.1.1.102.244&rep=rep1&type=pdf

It a story about your problem - I think

And remember that decimal is not fractional - where would you put the decimal point ?

Floatingpoints has this inside called mantissa ...

Comment: From the [Apple documentation on decimal numbers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/DecimalNumbers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000176-CJBCAGDI) (bold formatting is mine): "`NSDecimalNumber` is an immutable subclass of `NSNumber` that provides an object-oriented wrapper for doing base-10 arithmetic. **An instance can represent any number that can be expressed as `mantissa x 10 exponent` where *mantissa* is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and *exponent* is an integer between -128 and 127**."

Comment: Exactly - no fractions - just a lot of digits in the decimal world

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow what you mean. Could you provide some sample code illustrating your point with your answer?

Comment: It seems to be comma/point issue. I initially thought that it could concern floatpoint tolerances - I missed it ...