# how to calculate loan repayment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdecimalnumber

Hey I am trying to calculate monthly repayments based on loan amount, interest rate and number of years.

I have come up with the following, however there seems to be a difference between my calculations and other loan calculators on the internet. my test data was $1000 loan amount, 5% interest over a period of 1 year. this gives me a monthly payment of 85.61 and a total payment as 1027.29

Here is the code that calculates this.

```
    double LoanAmount = la; //loan amount
    double InterestRate = ir; //interest rate
    double NumberOfYears = noy; //number of years

    double interestRateDecimal = InterestRate / (12 * 100);
    double months = NumberOfYears * 12;
    double rPower = pow(1+interestRateDecimal,months);

    monthlyPayments = LoanAmount * interestRateDecimal * rPower / (rPower - 1);
    totalPayments = monthlyPayments * months;
    yearlyPayments = monthlyPayments * 12;
    totalInterest = totalPayments - LoanAmount;
```

Is the formula I am using correct or are there errors?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: first of all: don't use double if someone pays for that loan in real life. Use [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) See the [question "Should I use NSDecimalNumber to deal with money?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421463/should-i-use-nsdecimalnumber-to-deal-with-money) for the reasons

Comment: thanks for the tip, i'll look into this. btw what is the difference? as in what would happen if someone pays for that loan in real life.

Comment: @user1214037: the difference is in accuracy. One should **NEVER** use a float variable in app that deals with finance. You always use a kind of integer for the smallest ammount of money in currency you're working with. You can only convert to float when displaying the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should calculate your monthly payment.

```
NSDecimalNumber monthlyPayment = LoanAmount * interestRateDecimal / (1 - (pow(1/(1 + interestRateDecimal), months)));
```

I suggest using NSDecimalNumbers too.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into how I can use NSDecimalNumber, I am quite new to objective c so I don't really know everything that is available, but I learn, bit by bit. :)

Comment: Glad I could help. If it's the right answer, you can mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: I've looked a little into NSDecimalNumber however, I cannot pass doubles into NSNumber (like in the code you provided) so do I need to go and convert all my doubles into NSDecimalNumber? is it also possible to perform calculations like in the code you provided? - Also it gives me an error: interface type cannot be statically allocated.

Comment: Yes, it would be better to convert them. You could do it like this (example) ------- NSDecimalNumber *interestRateDec = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:InterestRate]; ------- But you can try it out by changing the monthlyPayment to double.

Comment: don't use `[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:]` Don't turn your doubles into NSDecimalNumbers at all. Use `[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.23"]` instead. Yes, NSDecimalNumbers are a PITA to use. But they provide accuracy. That's probably number 1 goal when you are dealing with financial software. Read this: http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/23/cocoa-tutorial-dont-be-lazy-with-nsdecimalnumber-like-me/

Comment: and of course you have to use the NSDecimalNumber methods to calculate. Don't use something like `[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:[decimalFoo doubleValue] + [decimalBar doubleValue]]` use `[decimalFoo decimalNumberByAdding:decimalBar]` instead. You see, big PITA. But accurate.

Comment: This isn't how `NSDecimalNumber`s work; that code snippet is completely wrong. `NSDecimalNumber` is a class; the variable needs to be a pointer, and it needs to be initialized with a method call, not just arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks for the info - it is a pain in the ... but I guess I need to learn how to use them

Answer (score 4):

I was a little bit bored so I put the monthly rate formula I got from the [internet](http://www.carpaymentcalculators.org/how-to-calculate-car-payments.html) into code that uses [NSDecimalNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

As you will see it's a big pita to use NSDecimalNumbers. But you are writing financial software, and your customers expect results that are correct.
And once again, I'm pointing you at Marcus Zarras article [DON’T BE LAZY WITH NSDECIMALNUMBER (LIKE ME)](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/23/cocoa-tutorial-dont-be-lazy-with-nsdecimalnumber-like-me/).

enjoy.

```
NSDecimalNumber *loan = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"25000"];
NSDecimalNumber *annualInterestRate = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"6"]; // 6%
annualInterestRate = [annualInterestRate decimalNumberByDividingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100"]]; // 0.06 i.e. 6%
NSInteger numberOfPayments = 36;

// (loan * (interest / 12)) / (1 - (1 + interest / 12) ^ -number)
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temp1
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temp2
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temp1
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temp4 
//                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temp5
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temp6
NSDecimalNumber *temp1 = [annualInterestRate decimalNumberByDividingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"12"]];
NSDecimalNumber *temp2 = [temp1 decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:loan];
NSDecimalNumber *temp4 = [[NSDecimalNumber one] decimalNumberByAdding:temp1];
NSDecimalNumber *temp5 = [[NSDecimalNumber one] decimalNumberByDividingBy:[temp4 decimalNumberByRaisingToPower:numberOfPayments]];
NSDecimalNumber *temp6 = [[NSDecimalNumber one] decimalNumberBySubtracting:temp5];

NSDecimalNumber *monthlyRate = [temp2 decimalNumberByDividingBy:temp6];
NSLog(@"Monthly rate: %@", monthlyRate);
```

hope it's correct though. I usually don't have to deal with NSDecimalNumbers.