# format to 2 decimal places before adding to array

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, arrays, formatting

Hey so I have test program for something I'm working on.

What does it do? - It basically minuses the monthly loan payments from the total amount payable and then inserts it into an array, it is working however I need it to be formatted to 2 decimal places and I have no idea how to do that, I've tried using a method I found which is

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2lf", tempPaymentHolder]
```

But it doesn't seem to work, here is the code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        //array that would hold the payments
        NSMutableArray * arrayWithPayments = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        //total amount to be paid
        NSMutableString * totalPaymentString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"151.92"];

        //monthly payment
        NSMutableString * monthlyPaymentsString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"12.66"];

        //temp storage for passing values into array
        NSMutableString * tempPaymentStringHolder = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        tempPaymentStringHolder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",totalPaymentString];

        //doubles so I can calculate
        int numberOfMonths = 12;
        double monthlyPayments = [monthlyPaymentsString doubleValue];
        double totalPayment = [totalPaymentString doubleValue];
        double tempPaymentHolder = totalPayment;


        for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfMonths; i++) 
        {
            [arrayWithPayments addObject:tempPaymentStringHolder];
            tempPaymentHolder = totalPayment - monthlyPayments;
            totalPayment = tempPaymentHolder;
            tempPaymentStringHolder = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2lf", tempPaymentHolder];
        }

        for (id obj in arrayWithPayments)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",obj);
        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Would appreciate any help.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What exactly is not working?  I ran your code and it prints out strings formatted to two decimal places which seems to match your specifications.

Comment: ah, thanks! it was working I was just looking at the wrong console output. sorry for the trouble

Comment: For currency, take a look at NSDecimalNumber's so that you don't have to worry about strange rounding errors of doubles.

Comment: Also, although you said this is just a test program - but converting back and forth between `NSString` and doubles doesn't make intuitive sense to me.  See excellent comments about `NSDecimalNumber` in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421463/should-i-use-nsdecimalnumber-to-deal-with-money)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfPayments = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//total amount to be paid
NSDecimalNumber * totalPayment = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"151.92"];

//monthly payment
NSDecimalNumber * monthlyPayments = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"12.66"];

//temp storage for passing values into array
NSDecimalNumber* tempPaymentHolder = [totalPayment copy];

//variables so I can calculate
int numberOfMonths = 12;


for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfMonths; i++) 
{
    [arrayOfPayments addObject:tempPaymentHolder];
    tempPaymentHolder = [totalPayment decimalNumberBySubtracting:monthlyPayments];
    totalPayment = [tempPaymentHolder copy];
}

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

for (NSDecimalNumber *obj in arrayOfPayments)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:obj]);
}
```

Output:

> $151.92
>   $139.26
>   $126.60
>   $113.94
>   $101.28
>   $88.62
>   $75.96
>   $63.30
>   $50.64
>   $37.98
>   $25.32
>   $12.66
>   $0.00

Just be sure to remember to copy variables where you would normally assign them, as you are dealing with objects, not primitives here!

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the wrong console output, sorry for the trouble and I will take a look at NSDecimalNumber - Thanks for the tip

Comment: +1, however, they aren't formatted to two decimals as requested. (An example of how to do this in addition to "upgrading" to NSDecimalNumber would answer the original question! )

Comment: @Inafziger, please check the answer again, obviously you hadn't recieved my edits, but I added number formatter in there too.