# Objective C Multiplication of floats gives unexpected results

Tags: objective-c, c, floating-point

I'm literately just doing a multiplication of two floats. How come these statements produce different results ? Should I even be using floats ?

500,000.00 * 0.001660 = 830

[image: Oddity Float Multiplications]

Comment: show assignment to curPrinciple and periodicInterest

Comment: After printing %.10f I realized there is plenty of decimal places in periodicInterest

Comment: @H2CO3: The discrepancy is too big. This is not floating point error.

Comment: showing assigmnet is not unnecessary because you get limited precision when you print float values

Comment: Turned out to be that Periodic Interest was actually 0.00165975093841552734 and NOT 0.001660. I found out after I did a NSLog(@"%.20f").

Comment: @ondav How do you know? (And then what is it? Oh well, read the comment above mine... it **was** a floating-point error...)

Comment: @H2CO3 A `float` can represent at least seven significant decimal digits accurately - in other words, it can represent decimal numbers with accuracy of 1 part in 10^7 or better.  Neither of the multiplicands in the question (500000 and 0.00166) have that many significant decimal digits.  The error in the output is (830-829.875488)/830 ≈ 0.00015, or 1.5 parts in 10^6 - too large for a single floating point rounding error, since IEEE 754 requires multiplication to return the `float` that is nearest, correctly rounded, to the exact result.  Thus the discrepancy is too big.

Comment: @robmayoff I see, then **what** do you call this error?

Comment: I call it an error.  Without seeing how he set `periodicInterest`, I can't be more specific.  He set `periodicInterest` to something significantly different than 0.00166 and then expected it to behave as if he had set it to 0.00166.  That is not a floating point error.

Comment: @H2CO3 A format error. Printing a number of small magnitude with the `%f` conversion is liable to obscure the actual values by suppressing many significant digits. If the magnitude is smaller than `5e-7`, the printing leaves no trace of any significant digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show how you initialized `periodicInterest`, and presumably you think you set it to `0.00166`, but in fact the error in your output is large enough that you must not have explicitly initialized it as `periodicInterest = 0.00166`.  It must be closer to `0.00165975`, and the difference between `0.00166` and `0.00165975` is definitely large enough not to just be a single floating-point rounding error.

Assuming you are working with monetary quantities, you should use [`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or  [`NSDecimal`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIDCDEJ).

One non-obvious benefit of using `NSDecimalNumber` is that it works with `NSNumberFormatter`, so you can let Apple take care of formatting currencies for all sorts of foreign locales.

#### UPDATE

In response to the comments:

- “`periodicInterest` is clearly not a monetary quantity” and “decimal is no more free of error when dividing by 12 than binary is” - for inexact quantities, I can think of two concerns:

  - One concern is using sufficient precision to give accurate results.  `NSDecimalNumber` is a floating-point number with 38 digits of precision and an exponent in the range -128…127.  This is more than twice the number of decimal digits an IEEE 'double' can store.  The exponent range is less than that of a `double`, but that's unlikely to matter in financial computing.  So `NSDecimalNumber`s can definitely result in smaller error than `float`s or `double`s, even though none of them can store 1/12 exactly.
  - The other concern is matching the results computed by some other system, like your bank or your broker or the NYSE.  In that case, you need to figure out how that other system is storing numbers and computing with them.  If the other system is using a decimal format (which is likely in the financial sector), then `NSDecimalNumber` will probably be useful.
- “Wouldn't it be more efficient to use primitive types to do floating point arithmetic, specially thousands in real time.”  Arithmetic on primitive types is far faster than arithmetic on `NSDecimalNumber`s.  I haven't measured it, but a factor of 100 would not surprise me.

  You have to strike a balance between your requirements.  If decimal accuracy is paramount (as it often is in financial programming), you must sacrifice performance for accuracy.  If decimal accuracy is not so important, you can consider carefully using a primitive type, but you should be aware of the accuracy you're sacrificing.  Even then, the size of a `float` is so small (usually only 7 significant decimal digits) that you should probably be using `double` (at least 15, usually 16 significant decimal digits).

  If you need to perform millions of arithmetic operations per second with true decimal accuracy, you might be able to do it using `double`s, **if you are an IEEE 754 expert** capable of analyzing your code to figure out where errors are introduced and how to eliminate them.  Few people have this level of expertise.  (I don't claim to.)   You must also understand how your compiler turns your Objective-C code into machine instructions.

  Anyway, perhaps you are just writing a casual app to compute a rough estimate of net present value or future value.  In that case, using `double` would probably suffice, but using `NSDecimalNumber` would probably also be sufficiently fast.  Without knowing more about the app you're writing, I can't give you more specific advice.

Comment: I would like to vote for this answer, since it states the correct reason for the observed behavior. However, I do not support blanket advice to use `NSDecimal`. `periodicInterest` is clearly not a monetary quantity. The interest for a period is likely to be one-twelfth the annual interest, and decimal is no more free of error when dividing by 12 than binary is. Even if it were, compound interest can easily exceed the precision of a fixed-precision format, regardless of base. What is needed is understanding of floating-point arithmetic, so that software can be written in light of its issues.

Comment: In the interest of picking a correct answer, this answer is most correct except for the NSDecimalNumber. I am not sure how efficient such method is. Wouldn't it be more efficient to use primitive types to do floating point arithmetic, specially thousands in real time. Rob, could you please explain or edit your answer before I vote for it ? By the way, the Periodic Interest was actually 0.00165975093841552734..... and NOT 0.001660. I found out after I tried a NSLog(@"%.20f").

Answer (score 5):

> How come these statements produce different results ?

Because [floating-point arithmetic is not exact](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and apparently you were not printing the multiplier precisely enough (i. e. with sufficient number of decimal digits). And it wasn't `.00166` but something that *seemed* `0.00166` rounded.

> Should I even be using floats ?

No. For money, use integers and treat them as fixed-point rational numbers. (They still aren't exact, but significantly better and less error-prone.)

Comment: @Bathsheba Great minds think alike :) (I don't know of any other reasonable/sane answer to this question.)

Comment: The difference is too big to be caused "just" by floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Re: "For money, use integers and treat them as fixed-point rational numbers", this is not going to be, conceptually, any better than using floats. Using fixed point rational numbers means that there is a constant resolution (e.g. for Q8 the resolution is 1/256), so you will be loosing precision just as with the floats. If numbers you will be using are rational and the operations on them preserve that (you do not do e.g. exp(x)) you could use any sort of arbitrary precision arithmetics, if you can accept the cons (I wouldn't but would instead use careful approach using either floats or Q).

Comment: @ondav "I wouldn't but would instead use careful approach using either floats or Q" - so do you suggest that "don't use rational numbers, but use rational numbers"?

Comment: Technically, fixed-point rational with a base of 10^-7 would be enough for almost any real-world situation.  There's no requirement (outside, perhaps, of efficiency) that the denominator be a power of 2.  That said, in my opinion ([and others'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421463/should-i-use-nsdecimalnumber-to-deal-with-money)), the correct answer is to use `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: @robmayoff Okay, thanks for your opinion (upvoted your answer because `NSDecimalNumber` seems to be the solution.)

Comment: One non-obvious benefit of using `NSDecimalNumber` is that it works with `NSNumberFormatter`, so you can let Apple take care of formatting currencies for all sorts of foreign locales.

Comment: @H2CO3: No I was just wondering what you find so much better on Q which floats miss. You say "1) don't use floats because they are not exact, 2) use fixed point rationals". SO readers could easily imply that Qs are exact, which they are not. So, I suggested a solution if someone wanted exactness, to complement your answer.

Comment: @ondav Okay, I see. I think you may want to add an answer as well, you provided valuable insights.