# Subtracting Currency - NSNumber

Tags: ios, currency, nsnumber

Im dealing with currency values that I need to subtract from each other. I read that NSNumber is good for dealing with currency, however I am unable to subtract two NSNumbers. Is there a better way for dealing with currencys or am I missing something small?

```
 NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        NSNumber* number = [numberFormatter  numberFromString:bDict[@"booking_deposit"]];
        if (!number) {
            [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
            number = [numberFormatter  numberFromString:bDict[@"booking_deposit"]];
        }
        NSNumber* number2 = [numberFormatter  numberFromString:bDict[@"booking_total"]];
        if (!number2) {
            [numberFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
            number2 = [numberFormatter  numberFromString:bDict[@"booking_total"]];
        }
        NSLog(@"result %@",number2 - number);//warning here
```

And heres the warning:

```
Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'NSNumber', which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform
```

Comment: `NSNumber` provides nothing other than wrapping primitive number types for storage within Objective-C collection classes.  Also attempting to subtract two objects using `-` indicates that you don't understand how objects work (or you assume operator overloading).

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks how would you go about dealing with currency?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421463/should-i-use-nsdecimalnumber-to-deal-with-money).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't subtract objects, that's why you get the error.

You could use `NSDecimalNumber` instead of `NSNumber` and then you have API for `decimalNumberBySubtracting:`.

Alternatively, use `double`.

The main point is to use a data type which allows for the level of precision that you're interested in, and that usually relates to the number of and type of calculations you're going to make.

`NSNumberFormatter` does offer `generatesDecimalNumbers` (it used to have a bug, not sure if it still does, worth investigation).

Comment: 'You can't subtract objects, that's why you get the error.' brain fart moment. Thanks ill check it out

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the type of value you stored in the NSNumber out to preform arithmetic.

```
NSLog(@"result = %f", [number2 doubleValue] - [number doubleValue])
```