# Do I really need to convert my project currency to NSDecimalNumber?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, currency, core-data-migration

Yes, I know I should use `NSDecimalNumber` to deal with currency, money, price... [I've read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421463/should-i-use-nsdecimalnumber-to-deal-with-money) The problem is, I adapted an existed project, which use `NSString` and `NSNumber` (`float`, `double`, `CGFloat`...) as currency. They deal with floating point by using `NSNumberFormatter`, as I can see it's not a big problem (yet?). Those currency is stored to coredata.

Now, if I want to convert all of those currency into `NSDecimalNumber`, I'll have to do a massive refactor in the code and migration in coredata. Here come the question:

> 1. If (I assume) `double`, `CGFloat`, `NSNumber` can hold the value as large as `NSDecimalNumber`, why should I use `NSDecimalNumber` since I can use
>      other with `NSNumberFormatter`? Is it because of performance?
> 2. In case of the necessary of the converting, can I do an auto migration with the help of MappingModel only, of course), or do I have
>      to adapt a custom migration policy?

Because the coredata use both `NSString` and `NSNumber` as currency, so please help me find a solution to migrate from both data type. I'm not used to work with `NSDecimalNumber` in coredata. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Okay, I got it that NSDecimalNumber is necessary. Please help me answer the second question: Can I do auto migration, using mappingModel + the thing like `FUNCTION($source.price, "decimalValue")` (this is incorrect since decimalValue return `NSDecimal`, not `NSDecimalNumber`). Do I really have to write a custom migration policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I really have to write a custom migration policy?

Yes. Create a subclass of NSEntityMigrationPolicy for each entity that needs conversion and implement the menthod createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:entityMapping:manager:error:. Enter the name of this class in the Custom Policy of the entity in the mapping model.

```
- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)sInstance
    entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager
    error:(NSError **)error
{
    BOOL aBool = [super createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:sInstance entityMapping:mapping manager:manager error:error];
    if (aBool)
    {
        NSArray *aSourceArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:&sInstance count:1];
        NSArray *aDestArray = [manager destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:[mapping name] sourceInstances:aSourceArray];
        if (aDestArray && [aDestArray count] > 0)
        {
            NSManagedObject *dInstance = [aDestArray objectAtIndex:0];
            // conversion
        }
    }
    return aBool;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Is it possible for me if I can only write one custom policy for all the entity need conversion? I guess I could, but the problem is I don't know when to perform conversion (`NSString` OR `NSNumber` to `NSDecimalNumber`). Can I check the class of the property in `destinationInstance`?

Comment: You can use the same migration policy for all entities but if the keys aren't the same you have to check the entity name for every managed object. You can check the class of the property in sInstance, the property in dInstance will be nil.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to create 1 policy for all the entities I need. Though the migration code might look ugly, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `double`, `CGFloat`, and those value types stored in `NSNumber` cannot precisely handle decimal values.  Thus, if you set 4.50, you may end up with some close approximation.  This is generally not desirable for monetary values, as you want exact representations.  You can perhaps get away with rounding using `NSNumberFormatter`, but if you start doing math with these values or need more accuracy than hundredths, you could end up with incorrect amounts.

I suspect you would have to do a heavy-weight migration to change the type of an attribute on a `CoreData` entity.  Even if you didn't have to, you might want to, so that you could ensure the values that you convert to `Decimal` are rounded to the precision you choose (since they may or may not be what you want in the database right now).

It sounds like you have some technical debt in your project.  Wether you choose to pay that debt down now or wait until it grows is up to you in the end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't want to do heavy migration, since it might be very complicate. Can I write something in the mapping model? Like to convert NSNumber, I'd write `FUNCTION($source.price, "decimalValue")`. But what about NSString? I'm not sure myself. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with mapping models, but `NSDecimalNumber` does have an `init` method that takes a `String` type.  I would add that storing monetary value numbers as a `String` is OK (although the space taken by a `String` in a database is larger than a `Decimal`).  You can continue to store them as `Strings` if you like and just create `NSDecimalNumber` values in code when you need to use them.  The real problem is the non-precise types like `double`/`float`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `NSDecimalNumber`, not `NSDecimal`. `NSDecimal` is a `struct`, while `NSDecimalNumber` is an Objective-C class that inherits from `NSNumber`. Thus you can usually pass an `NSDecimalNumber` wherever an `NSNumber` is accepted. `NSNumberFormatter` formats `NSDecimalNumber` instances automatically, and if you set your formatter's `generatesDecimalNumbers` to `YES`, it will parse strings into `NSDecimalNumber` instances.

The range of `NSDecimal` and `NSDecimalNumber` is larger than `double` or `CGFloat`. The decimal types store more significant digits and have a larger exponent range.

I don't know the answer to the auto migration question, but I do know that Core Data supports `NSDecimalNumber`. You can set an attribute's type to decimal (`NSDecimalAttributeType`) in your model.

Comment: Thank you, I know I was wrong about `NSDecimal` and `NSDecimalNumber`. And the second part (about migration) is more important than the first one.